# Show that a primitive group $G$ of degree $> 1$ is not regular if a point stabilizer $G_{ \alpha } $ equals its normalizer $N_{G} (G_{ \alpha } ) $.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

The following is part of an exercise from Permutation Groups by Dixon and Mortimer (Exercise 2.7.1); Show that a primitive group $G$ of degree $> 1$ is not regular if a point stabilizer equals its normalizer $ N_{G} (G_{ \alpha} ) $.

My attempt so far is as follows. Suppose $G_{ \alpha } \neq N_{G} (G_{ \alpha } ) $ for any $ \alpha $. As $G$ is primitive, each point stabilizer is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Now $ G_{ \alpha } < N_{G} (G_{ \alpha } ) \leq G$ and so $N_{G} (G_{ \alpha } ) = G $ by maximality of $G_{ \alpha } $. Thus $ G_{ \alpha } $ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Since all point stabilizers of a transitive group action are conjugate, $ G_{ \alpha } $ must stabilize every point.

I am not sure how to proceed here. If the action is faithful, then it must be that $G _{ \alpha } = \{ 1 \} $, which shows the action is regular and we are done.

I'm not sure how to deal with the situation where the action is not faithful. I also think this might just be some missing information from the book itself. Most websites seem to agree that the definition of a "primitive group" requires that the group has a faithful primitive group action on a set. However the textbook does not appear to include "faithful" in the definition of primitive group.

Comment: But a primitive group is just a group that acts primitively on a set, right? Closest I can find in the textbook to a definition of "primitive group" is "Let $G$ be a group which acts transitively on a set $ \Omega $. We say that the group is primitive if $G$ has no nontrivial blocks on $ \Omega $."

Comment: You seem to be trying to prove the converse of what you were asked to prove. In any case the question is about a primitive group not agroup acting primitively.

Comment: No a primitive group is defined as a subgroup of a symmetric group.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between a primitive group and a group acting primitively. I was under the impression they are the same. I could just be the book is missing a definition (I have found quite a few errors as I've been going through it).

Comment: Thanks, so a primitive group is automatically faithful if it is a subgroup of a symmetric group. I'm guessing the subgroup also has to act primitively on the set that the symmetric group naturally acts on?

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to bring actions into this question at all. I studied transitive and primitive permutation groups without any mention of group actions.

Comment: Well that's just how the textbook deals with primitive groups, in terms of groups acting on sets. I'm really just going off the definitions and terminology given in the book. It does seem to start using some terminology without clearly introducing it though - and it seems this use of "primitive group" is an example of that.